# MVVM Referencing Assemblies

Tags: windows, mvvm, view, model, viewmodel

I am implementing the MVVM pattern in the application I'm working on, and I have 3 seperated assemblies in my solution, the `Model, View, and ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` has a reference to the `Model`, and the `View` has a reference to the `ViewModel`.
In my `Model` I have a class `Event`, and in the `ViewModel` I create an `ObservableCollection<Event>`.
The problem is when I try to set this collection as the `DataContext` of a `ListView` in the `View`. I get this error:

```
error CS0012: The type 'Model.Event' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I want to have the app decoupled as much as possible, and this is not decoupling my app. I know that when I add a reference of the Model to my View, then I would not get the error, but I do not want my View having a Model Reference. How to make this working?

Comment: If you want your view to be able to display an `Event`, it has to have a reference, simple as that. I suppose you could have a 4th assembly of interfaces for your Models and have both your Model and View assemblies reference that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having your view assembly reference the model assembly.  I think it's common practice and the only way your going to get your models to display in your view.  Assuming you're binding to your view-model's ObservableCollection from your view's xaml (not code-behind), I don't see tightly coupled assemblies here.

Comment: Just because something is common practice doesn't make it a good idea. :)

Comment: @CameronMacFarland...Kind of like changing lanes without indicating.